# Unable to use mock HTTP/HTTPS get post request for json/xml response

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

Here is my code for junit.

I'm following this documentation  for mock-server http://www.mock-server.com/

```
mockServerClient=new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", 8080)
    .when(
            request()
                    .withMethod("POST")
                    .withPath("/login")
                    .withQueryStringParameters(
                            new Parameter("returnUrl", "/account")
                    )
                    .withCookies(
                            new Cookie("sessionId", "2By8LOhBmaW5nZXJwcmludCIlMDAzMW")
                    )
                    .withBody(exact("{username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}")),
            exactly(1)
    )
    .respond(
            response()
                    .withStatusCode(401)
                    .withHeaders(
                            new Header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                            new Header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400")
                    )
                    .withBody("{ message: 'incorrect username and password combination' }")
                    .withDelay(new Delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1))
    );
```

The problem is request, response, exactly, exact, Header are not getting resolved in editor.
Some additional imports must be required but I couldn't find any working example/alternate to it.

All I need is simply mocking a server url request and responses to be used in Junits.
As an alternative to mock server I also tried Mockwebserver-https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

but it too has many limitations like I'm unable to do post using mockwebserver.
Also checking other options suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393099/mocking-http-server.
If anyone knows a working solution please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to work it with [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? If so maybe you can try my mock server instead?
https://mockserver.codeplex.com/

Comment: No I'm Working on Ubuntu.
But I will try this as well later